# Android Studioが起動できません

Tags: java, macos, android-studio

Android studioを起動しようとすると以下のメッセージが表示されてしまいます。
これを解決したいです。

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: bootstrap.jar が見つからないため lib ディレクトリーを特定できません
AOP 起動トランスフォーマーの開始に失敗しました。
```

使用機器はM1のmacbook airです。

#### 試したこと

1. Android Studio,Javaの完全アンインストール
2. Android Studioを `~/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/` の下にある `studio` からの立ち上げ
3. 起動オプションに `-clean` をつけての実行

どうかよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

パスはもう通しましたか？
画面キャプチャなどがあると分かりやすいかもしれないです。

大体のAndroidStudioの初期の起動しないは、
パスが通っていないことがほとんどです。
パスを通したら、再起動も必要です。
パスの通し方などで検索してみるといいと思います。
http://www.programing-style.com/android/android-tool/android-studio-setup-mac/